# M2 Product import problems using multiple images per product

Tags: magento2, product-images, import

I am trying to import a csv file. But there is one error I do not understand and I do not know how to get over it.
The error message is the follwing:

> Product Type is invalid or not supported in row(s): 2,.... (many more rows are affected but all are built the same way)

The affected fields in the csv look like this:
[image]

Is this the wrong approach in M2? Should I use the additional_images field instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Magento 2 format of CSV file has been changed. The main difference is:

- In `Magento 1` field values can allocate multiple cells in a column.
- In `Magento 2` field values can allocate only one cell. Delimiter is used for separation.

As for images, you must use:

- `base_image` - for base image
- `small_image` - for small one
- `thumbnail_image` - for thumbnail
- `additional_images` - for all other
  images in format(comma-separated):  `2.png,3.png,4.png`

To understand format better export some products and take a look into received CSV file.

**UPDATE**

Answer to comment.

No, it's not a bug.

Every column represents some product EAV attribute.

- `base_image` - `image` attribute
- `small_image` - `small_image` attribute
- `thumbnail_image` - `thumbnail` attribute
- `additional_images` - `media_gallery` attribute

`media_gallery` contains all assigned images, other attributes just assign role(base, small or thumbnail) to image.

Comment: many thanks, I got it now. Somehow the tutorials I looked at did not clearly inform about that change.

Comment: one more question: I exported a product with two images, 1.png is the base image, but in my export file it is in the base image field and also lined up in the additional_images field like: 1.png, 2.png
Is this a bug?